# Installing Outlook Addin created from Visual Studio 2013 to Office 365

Tags: outlook, add-in

I have created a Sample Outlook AddIn from Visual Studio 2013, Same AddIn I can see in my Desktop Office Outlook. I would like to install AddIn created to Office 365 Web. Can anybody help me to install Add in Created from VIsual Studio to Office 365 Web?

Appreciate your help in advance.

Thanking you,
Amit Waychal

Comment: Did you create a Visual Studio Tools For Office (VSTO) add-in using VB.NET or C#, or a web add-in using HTML and JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can install Add Ins that you have created in Visual Studio onto your Office 365 Web account by logging into your web account on the 365 website and navigating to the Manage Add Ins section of the settings menu, as seen below.

[Image showing where to access Manage Add Ins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7Uq5.png)

Once you have accessed this menu, on the top right you will see a button that reads "install custom add in", click it, and then click the '+' symbol on the left of the screen to add your Add In.

Hope this helps.